# Have NHibernate ignore not set properties?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a **huge** object, it has a lot of lazy loadable properties.

I want to enable a quick edit of a very small subset of its property.
How can I, when I just have a few values, tell NHibernate: don't touch anything else?

Because now, when I save, everything not set gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [dynamic-update](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) option on your class mapping?

```
<class name="SomeEntity" dynamic-update="true">
```

But check if the flush does not cause the unloaded lazy properties to get loaded first, just in case.

In your question, you state you lose other properties. I have never witnessed such a behavior. Are you attaching (using `ISession.Update` or `ISession.Merge`) a detached entity in your current code?
What I am suggesting will not work in such a case. It should instead work with an entity loaded from the current `ISession`, touched on some properties then saved to db only using `ISession.Flush` (or preferably, `ITransaction.Commit`, since it is not a good practice to work without transactions).